# Scala-Java incompatibility referencing static fields in a class with the same name as a static inner class

Tags: scala, inner-classes, scala-java-interop

Take this Java class:

```
public class Fisk {

    public static class A {
    }

    public static A A = new A();
}
```

This Java code works:

```
    Fisk.A a = new Fisk.A();
    Fisk.A b = Fisk.A;
```

But calling it from Scala:

```
    val fisk = new Fisk.A()
    val strupp = Fisk.A
```

results in compiler-error:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[INFO] both variable A in object Fisk of type Fisk.A
[INFO] and  object A in object Fisk of type object Fisk.A
[INFO] match expected type ?
[INFO]          val strupp = Fisk.A
[INFO]                                   ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

Anyone knows a way around this, or do I have to rename my static field?

--
Andreas

Comment: Did you try to give an explicit type, e.g. `val strupp: Fisk.A = Fisk.A` ?

Comment: Giving an explicit type makes it compile using Maven, but gives error in IDEA:

error: A is already defined as object A
public static A A = new A();

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> Fisk.A
<console>:8: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both variable A in object Fisk of type Fisk.A
and  object A in object Fisk of type object Fisk.A
match expected type ?
       Fisk.A
            ^
// this is the static field A of Fisk
scala> Fisk.A: Fisk.A
res1: Fisk.A = Fisk$A@d86c58

// this is a new constructed instance of type Fisk.A
scala> val fisk = new Fisk.A()
fisk: Fisk.A = Fisk$A@462f90

// this is the static field A of Fisk (see the same hashcode)
scala> val strupp: Fisk.A = Fisk.A
strupp: Fisk.A = Fisk$A@d86c58
```

Comment: I've filed a ticket to Jetbrains as it works using explicit type, but for some reason doesn't compile in IDEA: [http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-3146](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-3146)
Please vote for it:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an explanation together with a solution](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5302484#5302484).